# DOS BAT Command: Verifying SQL PLUS SQL Query

Tags: batch-file, sqlplus

I had created the following command in my .bat file:

```
@echo select count(*) from table where column1 = 'abc'; | sqlplus username/password@database
```

Depending on the result returned, I need it different SQLs. How can I do it?

e.g. if the resultset returned is 0, I need it to exit the .bat file. If the resultset is not 0 (1 or >1), then I will execute another SQL statement.

Please help.

Comment: You should learn PLSQL as well as SQL*PLUS scripting and put your logic in one place. There is no need for context switching (batch to Oracle to batch to Oracle) as you describe in your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how output is provided but something like the following should work:

```
@echo off
set tempfile=%temp%\%random%.log
echo select count(*) from table where column1 = 'abc'; | sqlplus username/password@database > "%tempfile%"
findstr /c:"INVALID" "%tempfile%" >nul 2>&1 && echo No resultset || echo some other statement | sqlplus username/password@database
```

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to understand your statement.

How can I make it in such a way that, if the resultset returned is 0, it will prompt the user "No resultset" before it exits?

Comment: Maybe I can create different section in the .BAT file?

If the resultset is 0, goto :section1. If the resultset is <> 0, goto :section2. How can I do that?

Comment: So, I had modified my SQL query to return a more unique value, i.e. VALID or INVALID.

I also am using
    findstr /c:"VALID" scriptlog.txt >nul 2>&1
    rem string is found
    if errorlevel 0 goto valid
    rem string not found
    if errorlevel 1 goto invalid


But I am not able to redirect the statement correctly. Am I doing it correctly?